# tool for converting csv file to vcard 2.1 and 3.0

Tags: vcf-vcard

Are there any command line tools to generate vcard files on unix platform? I did some research and either there are some commercial softwares or applications like KDE or akonadi to store contacts.

I would either have the contact information in csv or db and the tools should either generate a vcard 2.1 or 3.0 depending on some input.

Found some links to a bash script, but that doesnt seem to work.

Please suggest.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

I successfully converted vcards from version 2.1 to version 3.0  using [vcard2to3](https://github.com/jowave/vcard2to3):

```
git clone https://github.com/jowave/vcard2to3.git
cd vcard2to3
./vcard2to3.py your_file.vcf
```

Answer (score 2):

The Java library [ez-vcard](https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard) can do this:

```
File fromFile = new File("vcard-2.1.vcf");
File toFile = new File("vcard-3.0.vcf");

Ezvcard.write(Ezvcard.parse(fromFile).all()).
    version(VCardVersion.V3_0).go(toFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the default Kubuntu KAddressBook program (18.04). Just import a VCF 2.1 file and export it again.

You can choose different formats for export:

```
 -vCard 2.1
 -vCard 3.0
 -vCard 4.0
 -CSV
 -LDIF
```